Itext PDF Java Lanuage
I am creating PDF from html in java with help to itext pdf 7
File Generated successfully but in the output the letters are get shuffled
i.e expected output  வழங்கப்பட்ட தேதி
actual output வழங்கப்பட்ட ததி
Sample code
public static final String ARABIC = "வழங்கப்பட்ட தேதி -- கொடுக்கப்பட்ட தேதி";

 protected String PDFInTamil(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\noto-sans-tamil\\NotoSansTamilRegular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

    // It is required to add iText typography dependency to handle correctly arabic text
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is auto detection: ");
    p.add(new Text(ARABIC).setFont(f));
    p.add(new Text(": 50.00 USD"));
    doc.add(p);

    doc.close();
    return null;
 }
}


As @KJ implies, you should try iText in combination with the iText Core add-on pdfCalligraph. They claim that combination can handle Tamil.

Eat-your-own-dogfood is not so common nowadays... ;)
